# Difference between += and add to a MutableList in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

After looking at `+=` to a mutableList, I could not figure out what it was immediately, my imagination was `i = i+1` where `i` is an integer, which does not make sense in the below code, but after debugging I realized it was just adding an item to the list, so my question is what difference it makes to use `+=` to add an item to list rather than just using mutableList.add(item), which is more readable at least in my case. Thank in advance.

```
musicSource.forEach { mediaItem ->
            val albumMediaId = mediaItem.album.urlEncoded
            val albumChildren = mediaIdToChildren[albumMediaId] ?: buildAlbumRoot(mediaItem)
            albumChildren += mediaItem
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference.  
`+=` is an inline operator, and in `MutableCollections.kt` its implementation is:

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline operator fun <T> MutableCollection<in T>.plusAssign(element: T) {
    this.add(element)
}
```

As you can see it uses the `add()` method.  
You can use it or not. It's your choice.  
This is more readable `x = x + 1`, but we tend to use `x++`.

Comment: I agree with `x++` to a number because that was how we learned the basics of a programming language, but `+=` to a list was new to me.

Comment: @SaiKiran I never use += for a list

Comment: he he he... but I feel like might start using it because we need to adapt to stuff and reconsider what we learned as basics.

Comment: @SaiKiran I don't consider this to be the case. Kotlin has far more interesting things to focus.

Answer (score 2):

It's one of the [operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) convention in Kotlin.

The compiler will translate expression like `a += b` to `a.plusAssign(b)` if type `a` implements the `plusAssign` operator function. It gives you power to write more expressive code.

Answer (score 1):

1. `+=` for MutableList(in case you use), the compiler performs the following steps:

> -If the function from the right column is available
>
> - If the corresponding binary function (i.e. plus() for plusAssign()) is 
>     available too, report error (ambiguity),
>
>   - Make sure its return type is Unit, and report an error otherwise,
>   - Generate code for a.plusAssign(b);
> - Otherwise, try to generate code for a = a + b (this includes a type check: the type of a + b must be a subtype of a).

2. `add` function for MutableList :

> return true if the element has been added, false if the collection
>   does not   support duplicates and the element is already contained in
>   the collection.

Note : Please don't forget `add()` also have option to add element in specific index eg. `add(index: Int, element: E)`

Documentation

[https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#assignments](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/add.html)

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/add.html